# Mat <> BufferedImage conversion in OpenCV 3

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

Apparently it was possible in OpenCV 2.4 with Java bindings to convert a `Mat` into a `BufferedImage`:

```scala
val greyMat = new Mat()
opencv_imgproc.cvtColor(mat, greyMat, opencv_imgproc.CV_BGR2GRAY, 1)
ImageIO.write(greyMat.getBufferedImage, "jpg", new File("output_grey.jpg"))
```

I tried updating a project that used this code (and it worked, I checked) to use OpenCV 3.1, and it seems this method has gone.

Why is this method `getBufferedImage` removed from API, and how do I get back to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a separate converter class now: `Java2DFrameConverter`:

```scala
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Java2DFrameConverter

val greyMat = new Mat()
val conv = new Java2DFrameConverter
opencv_imgproc.cvtColor(mat, greyMat, opencv_imgproc.CV_BGR2GRAY, 1)
ImageIO.write(conv.getBufferedImage(greyMat), "jpg", new File("output_grey.jpg"))
```